# Faster attribute access in python

Tags: python, pylint

Consider the following class:

```
class MyObject(object):

    __slots__ = ('_att1', '_att2')

    def __init__(self):
        self._att1 = None
        self._att2 = None

    @property
    def att1(self):
        """READ-ONLY property. """
        return self._att1

    @property
    def att2(self):
        """att2 property description. """
        return self._att2

    @att2.setter
    def att2(self, val):
        self._att2 = val
```

An advantage of using the property decorator is that we can add some documentation

```
a = MyObject()
help(a)
Help on MyObject in module __main__ object:

class MyObject(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  att1
 |      READ-ONLY property.
 |  
 |  att2
 |      att2 property description.
```

If the class is meant to be used by the final user then it is fine to access the attributes
by using the properties.

```
a.att2 = "new value"
```

However, if I were to derive a class from `MyObject`, is it acceptable to use the "protected" variables in the derived class? That is,

```
 class Derived(MyObject):

     __slots__ = ()

     def __init__(self):
         self._att1 = 1
         self._att2 = 0

     @property
     def att2(self):
         """att2 adds 1 to itself in every call. """
         self._att2 += 1
         return self._att2

     @att2.setter
     def att2(self, val):
         self._att2 = val
```

I'm aware that if `MyObject` was an object from a third party then the attributes with underscore are subject to change and thus my code would break if they ever do change. However, since I am using `MyObject` as a base class I would think that it is fine to use this with my own derived classes.

I recently started using `pylint` and it made me aware of the fact that I am using "protected" variables in my derived classes. The reason I decided to post a question here is to know if this is something acceptable to do so that I can just suppress those warnings in `pylint`. If it isn't, then what is the standards to deal with this?

Another point I would like to make is about the attribute access. What would be faster

```
a.att1
```

or

```
a._att1
```

I'm under the impression that by doing `a.att1` python would first look in the objects dictionary, or slots as in the example I am working with. If that isn't located there when it looks for functions (as is in the case with the [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)). When doing a lot of computations in my class definition I rather access something located in the dictionary or in the slots as opposed to the ones I defined with the decorators. Is this considered bad practice among the python community? I'm only asking this since the default configuration of `pylint` tells me otherwise and I would like to continue working having good standards in mind.

### EDIT:

Let us try not to get into the discussion of `__slots__` and premature optimization. If possible
assume that in my original post I did not use `__slots__` and that everything is in the object's dictionary.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is bad in general, your *reason* for wanting this is a bad one (doubly so because it is not backed by hard data). You shouldn't increase coupling based on a gut feeling that it's a bit faster.

Comment: @delnan, I'm not sure why it is a bad one. Could you please explain.

Comment: Also notice that lookups in dictionaries are `O(1)`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have a formal distinction between private and protected class members. Even the distinction between private and public is pretty weak, since anything can be accessed if a user tries hard enough. If a private versus protected distinction would make sense for your application, you can simply document that `_foo` (or `foo`) is not part of the public user interface, but can be relied upon by subclasses to always have certain semantics. (What those semantics are is up to you.)

Now, I don't know if it's really worth the documentation effort to do this for a simple read-only property (the function call overhead is likely not too bad, so subclasses can just use the property like everyone else). However, if you had a property that was doing a lot more work, like a database query or HTTP request, it might make some sense for the internals to be exposed a bit for subclasses to get at just the parts they need.

If you do think that exposing the "protected" value is desirable, the only question is whether you should put the underscore in front of the variable name or not. The underscore has a few effects on things like `dir` and perhaps in documentation generating tools, but it doesn't change anything about how the code runs.

So it's really an issue of code style, and it really doesn't matter much either way. You can either leave the underscore off and put big warning text in the documentation so that users know they shouldn't be messing with the internals, or you could use the underscore and silence the pylint warnings (and if necessary, force there to be some extra docs for subclass implementors).

Comment: This is actually how I made up my mind yesterday after reading the other answers and comments. I should have mentioned the first point in my post (no formal distinction between public, private and protected). I had known this the first time I learned how to make classes. I just thought it would be a good idea to verify conventions and standards with others so that if I ever expose what I write people won't be so lost. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Attributes with underscore are not “protected”, but “private”—they are subject to change. Even if your class is derived from it. You should use parent property to access this data.

Speaking about performance. Of course, property access is a bit slower than attribute access, simply because it involves a function call, but you shouldn't care about it. By the way it has nothing to do with `__getattr__` and all this stuff. Properies are also looked up in the dictionary as normal attributes, they just implement the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).

Comment: What about cases where the base class has a function which takes in derived objects? It seems like a waste of time to go through the function when you know already that `_att` and `att` return the same value.

Comment: Sure it does. It's always your decision: you either follow some programming practices (OOP in this example) or you don't. Choosing to follow gives you idiomatic code which will be easy to read and maintain, probably it will be more robust. Choosing not to follow gives you performance.

Comment: Or I could always leave a comment saying that `_att` and `att` are the same and get something that others can read and understand and get some performance.

Comment: Also, please not, that method resolution order is not as simple as you might thing. The fact that your class `Derived` is dervied from class `MyClass` doesn not mean that `MyClass` will _immediately_ follow `Derived` in the method resolution chain. So if someone else extends `MyClass` it is possible that super call (super property access) in `Derived` will go to this new class, not `MyClass`. This means that your shortcut will completely break things.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Trust pylint. See if you really have a performance problem. If yes, profile and than go for the bottlenecks. Changing a loop or a data structure is likely much more effective.

Comment: In this case, my baseclass defines all the properties that the derived objects will have, but the derived objects will behave differently. I want to keep the variables "protected" mainly to have them behave as read only variables, the users can of course access the protected variables at their own risk. I could change everything to not have the underscore and I would have the exact same thing (functionality wise) but now the users and even myself will not know if that particular attribute is meant to be accessed as read only or not.